# How can I monitor failed job steps on SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, monitoring

We have two MS SQL servers (one 2000 and one 2005) that run a number of jobs at various time during the day and night. These jobs have a number of steps that will pull data from an Informix database (our business system) and update tables for use by various reporting and production systems.

We had a failure of these imports over the weekend which resulted in many reporting systems giving wrong data.

Due to security restrictions we are not able to enable sending emails from the servers so how can we monitor these job effectively without having to constantly check the Job status in Enterprise manager or MS SQL Studio? Is it possible to run a query on the servers and find the status of various jobs?

Comment: You cannot send an email?!  Ouch.  Not even to say 'check the job logs, something failed'?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are several different ways to monitor the output of sql server jobs.

**Option 1: Monitoring Tool, Such as Sitesope, MOM/SCOM, or Custom**
For most production instances, you want to have an enterprise monitoring tool which will scan for OS and SQL related errors. Typically you set your Sql Agent jobs to write to the Windows event log when they fail, and your monitoring tool frequently reads the Windows event log and will alert you based on conditions you define. You can purchase a monitoring system such as SiteScope, or create your own tool to look for these errors. You could also use a tool like Logparser to read these logs.

I mention this option first because if your reporting system is critical, you probably want to invest in a reliable monitoring system long term. Short term you could do some custom scripting if you wanted to go the Windows Log route.

**Option 2: Querying MSDB**
All sql job history is stored in the MSDB database, and you can indeed query it. You can do this both from query windows or from a custom tool-- for instance, you could create a powershell script that periodically connects to your each of your servers and queries the msdb database for given conditions and alerts accordingly.

I have written a couple of blog entries which have sample scripts for querying sql job history. None of them do *exactly* what you're asking for, but they will help you work with the way dates are stored in MSDB, which can be a bit tricky as they aren't stored in datetime fields: http://thedbaknows.wordpress.com/category/sql-agent/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Have been using a solution based on ideas in your blog. We run a query each morning that looks for failed steps and it works brilliantly. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

Every time I mention this I get shouted at, but I'll mention it anyway because it works for me.

Virtually anything you do as a SQL job you can do from a batch file using osql to run the appropriate SQL commands. The advantage of a batch file is that you have great flexibility in how you analyse the results and send notifications if there are any errors. Especially so if you use Powershell. Just run the batch file from the Windows scheduler.

The usual criticism is that this is a non-standard way to do things, and I guess it is. However I have over a hundred servers scattered across the North West of the UK and using batch files (and some VBScript) to run database backup and maintenance tasks and analyse the results is the best way I've found to make things managable.

JR

Comment: I shudder at the thought of having to manage tasks without msdb

Comment: I suspect this is a cultural thing. I run all my scripts from one server so I can see at a glance everything that's being run by opening one .bat file in Notepad, and I can see what time(s) they run by running \\myserver and looking in the scheduled tasks. To an old time command line nerd like me this seems easy.

Answer (score 2):

If your monitoring app can run a SQL Statment:

You can run sp_help_job and drop the results into a table, then look for jobs which have a last_run_outcome of 0.  If there are any have the monitoring app send out an email.

Or better yet, inform your management that the restriction that the SQL Server can't send mail is adversely effecting you from proactively monitoring the SQL Server as the SQL Server can not be used to it's fullest capabilities by alerting the DBAs where there is a job failure.

I assume you use some sort of Enterprise class mail system (Exchange, Lotus, etc).  Setup the SQL Server to send mail via SMTP to the mail system, and setup the mail system so that the SQL Server can only email the DBAs.  This way there shouldn't be any worries about the SQL Server magically sending email to people who shouldn't be getting them.

What's the logic behind not letting the SQL Servers send email anyway?